# Disable JavaScript for specific section

Tags: javascript, html

Hi so I'm working on a little project and I keep running into an issue with my script I have used it in the past with no problems but this time it's affecting my one section/div in a very weird way.. It just isn't there.. All the others are fine but this one.. so is there maybe a way to disable this script for that selected bit if code?

Note I only want to disable the one script for that one section..

Thanks in advance, I'm new so sorry if I'm doing this wrong xD

Comment: You question is extremely poor quality. How is anyone in the world supposed to give an answer based on the information you provide?

Comment: you can provide some code examples.

Comment: voting for closing post off-topic with unclear issue

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you are intending to prevent scripts in a page from running in a certain section of your webpage, wrapping it up in an `iframe` will do.